# PHP: Split header into spans

Tags: php

I have a simple content rotator that displays text like so:

```
<h4><span>Featured Article</span></h4> 
                        <h2><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</span> <span>consectetur adipisicing elit</span></h2> 
                        <span class="author">by Cameron Drysdale</span>
```

As you can see the h2 has it's text split up into `<span>` tags. This is so I can achieve the following effect as seen here on the pink box: http://www.paperviewmagazine.com/

The problem is how to do this automatically as the header will be generated from a database and will not have the span tags by default. Any ideas on how I could use PHP to add in some tags to wrap certain parts of a title?

**EDIT: I'm using WordPress and so the title would be shown like `<?php the_title(); ?>` and I'd probably want to split the text after x number of characters**

**EDIT2: I should note that the idea is to split the content using span tags so this could also be a possibility: `<span>this is</span> <span>some text</span> <span>I'm sharing</span>`**

Comment: How do you want to identify the position in the string where to wrap? Just random? Or after x chars? Or after a comma?

Comment: good point, i guess after say 3-4 words

Answer (score 0):

What is the criteria you use for splitting.
Assuming it's a comma (you could use number of words/letters etc), just split the string using

```
<? $arr= explode(",",$your_db_field);?>
<span><?=$arr[0]?></span><span><?=$arr[1]?></span>
```

Comment: And if there is more than one comma?

Comment: then you have $arr[2], all depends on how you wish to separate the string. You could take the first part before comma, and use the rest as the next line split.

Comment: Or use `explode(",", $your_db_field, 2)` in order to only split once :)

Comment: @Mr. Zen what about splitting on every 4 words?

Comment: Read about strtok. You can tokenize the string using space , just like explode.

Answer (score 0):

A few questions:  Why is your  content broken into two sections when your example shows that they are the same font? is there always going to be a comma followed by a line break?

Reason I ask is because you could simply insert your title into an array and explode() on the comma.

> EDIT: I'm using WordPress and so the
>   title would be shown like  and I'd probably want
>   to split the text after x number of
>   characters

Okay that makes more sense. As far as I'm aware, there's no need for you to use multiple  tags:

```
<?php

    $chars_per_line = 15;
    $title = "This is my title and I hope you like my article";
    $title_length = strlen($title);
    $lines = ceil($title_length / $chars_per_line);

    for ($i=0; $i<$lines; $i++) {
        $pos_start = $i * 15;
        $pos_end = $pos_start + ($chars_per_line - 1);
        echo substr($title, $pos_start, $pos_end) . '<br />';
    }

?>
```

Comment: The content is split so that I can have the wrap effect with the background colours. The comma being at the end of the first line is coincidental. An example in the OP is also a valid possibility.

Comment: Cheers for the code, but `<br/>` won't work. It needs to be span tags wrapping sections of the title.

Comment: What about nesting a table with a defined width inside your pink box table? That would effectively force your text to wrap without having to get into breaking apart title strings. As for your previous comment, adjust the echo statement accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If your text has `<br/>` tags or `\n` you can split it in array and then iterate over it.

```
$lines = split('<br/>',$text);
foreach($lines as $line){
   echo "<span>".$line."</span>";
}
```

of course you can also use the comma to split the text.

to split the text by char length btw. you can use this.

```
$lenght = 100;
$start = 0;
$lines = array();

while(strlen($text) < $start)) {
  $lines[] = substr($text, $start, $start+$length);
  $start += $length; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a span to achive the wanted result. You could just encapsulate you `h2` in a `div` with a fixed width and the content will automatically flow on two line if it's to long.

Just make sure if you use this technique to you non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) as spaces between the last words to avoid orphans.

I you really want to break it on specific chars, I would then go with `Mr. Zen`'s answer

**Edit:**

Here is a link to a valid demo http://jsfiddle.net/38srk/3/

**Edit (again):**

I still think that a full html/css solution is still the best, but if you really want to do it in PHP here is a beginning for your solution :

```
$str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit';
$words = explode(' ', $str);
$nbWords = count($words);
$nbWordsPerLine = 4;

$output = '<span>';
for($i = 0; $i < $nbWords; $i++) {
    if($i % $nbWordsPerLine == 0
       && $i > 0
    ) {
        $output .= '</span><span>';
    }
    $output .= $words[$i];
    if ($i + 1 < $nbWords){
       $output .= ' ';
    }
}
$output .= '</span>';

echo $output;
```

This will give you something like that :

```
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit </span><span>amet, consectetur adipisicing elit </span>
```

Comment: I need the spans so I can have the inline background color if I use the h2 background it will be block which isn't what I want.

Comment: Cheers for the demo. It does give a similar effect but it doesn't properly break up the words like my example does hence the need for the span tags.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you haven't already designed the db, simply have two fields - title_line_1 and title_line_2. No need to split.